# Gradle configurations.runtime excluding compileOnly

Tags: gradle, configuration, compilation, runtime, war

Gradle 4: how to get all the jars that will be in a war or APK?

```
configurations.runtime
```

returns all the jars for runtime, but it includes those jars in compileOnly

```
compileOnly group: 'A', name : 'foo', version : '1.0'
```

How to exclude the foo.jar since it is compileOnly for java library.

What is the java class for configurations?

### UPDATE

It is actually providedCompile, not compileOnly. compileOnly jars are not included in configurations.runtime, but providedCompile jar are included (should not).

Comment: The class for configurations is [org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html), but `compileOnly` is not part of `runtime` if you didn't add it. Can you please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you can show the behavior you describe?

Comment: It is actually providedCompile jars are included. updated question.

Comment: Why do you want to use `providedCompile` instead of `compileOnly`?

Comment: compileOnly is for java-library. prividedCompile for java/war.

Comment: `compileOnly` is for both, `java` *and* `java-library`. Yes, for `war` it would be `providedCompile`, but not for `java`. `providedCompile` were done differently than `compileOnly`. You need to subtrace `providedCompile` from `runtime` to get what you expect. Or you should not use `providedCompile` after all.